# Is there any generic way to call method of child class but the parameter is child of another type?

Tags: java, templates, genetics

For example, I have 3 child classes:

```
public interface IPrinter{
}

public class StringPrinter implements IPrinter{
    public String getInfo(String input){
        return "String value:"+input;
    }
}

public class IntegerPrinter implements IPrinter{
    public String getInfo(Integer input){
        return "Integer value:"+input.intValue();
    }
}

public class BooleanPrinter implements IPrinter{
    public String getInfo(Boolean input){
        return "Boolean input:"+input.booleanValue();
    }
}
```

which they are child of IPrinter, and the parameters are child of Object.

In my business code, the call of the object must be placed between some other long code (eg:loops or if-else),to get different values by different types, each time I have to copy and paste codes outside,eg:

```
for(a){
    if(b){ 
        result=new StringPrinter().getInfo("abc");
    }
}

for(a){
    if(b){ 
        result=new IntegerPrinter().getInfo(new Integer(123));
    }
}

for(a){
    if(b){ 
        result=new BooleanPrinter().getInfo(new Boolean(true));
    }
}
```

now I want a magic function which can determine which to call automatically, eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    result=magicGetInfo<StringPrinter,String>(new StringPrinter(),"abc");
}

public static String magicGetInfo(IPrinter p,Object o){
    for(a){
        if(b){ 
          //magic code, may be using template
        }
    }
}
```

is there any way to do this? I tried:

```
public class StringPrinter implements IPrinter{
    public String getInfo(String input){
        return "String value:"+input;
    }
}

public interface IPrinter {
    <Input extends Object> String getInfo(Input input);
}

public static <P extends IPrinter,I extends Object> String getInfo(P p,I  i,Class<? extends P> c){
    try{
        return ((IPrinter)c.newInstance()).getInfo(i);
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

but StringPrinter cannot compile:

```
class 'StringPrinter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method
```

Comment: How is `result=getInfo<StringPrinter,String>("abc");` preferable to `result=new StringPrinter().getInfo("abc");`? What's "automatic" about it?

Comment: Your input should be class not the instance